# People with autism: Sliding divs or show/hide toggle?

Tags: forms, accessibility, hidden

I am working on a site where we are designing with an emphasis on accessibility. One of these groups we have in mind is people with autism.

We have some forms with radio buttons. Some of the answers will need clarification or more details, depending on the answer. An example:

```
1) Do you have any hobbies? [Radio button: Yes] [Radio button: No]
2) Do you like dragons? [Radio button: Yes] [Radio button: No]
```

If you answer yes to 1), we want to ask what hobbies by inserting a textbox:

```
1) Do you have any hobbies? [Radio button selected: Yes] [Radio button: No]
1a) What hobbies do you have? [Textbox]
2) Do you like dragons? [Radio button: Yes] [Radio button: No]
```

Obviously, we only want to show 1a) if the answer to 1) is "Yes". What is the best way to change it from being hidden to showing on the page, without it being too stimulating? Just to make it clear, not only would there be new information on the page, but the content on the rest of the page would be pushed down.

**THE QUESTION:** Do we just change the CSS for Ia) from display:none; to display:block;, pushing the rest of the page down instantly, or would we be better "sliding" it onto the page, using animation? (This would be done slowly, to avoid being too stimulating).

Answers would be grateful appreciated, and if you had a source for them that would be even better (but I am interested in anecdotal evidence as well). Many thanks!

Comment: Could you reveal each question separately instead of showing the whole form up-front? Then you wouldn't have to worry about showing/hiding content, plus it'd keep the focus on the current question with less distractions around the screen. That has negatives in that it's unclear how long the form is going to be though as you can't see it all in one go, so that needs considering.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, Jon, but splitting the form to one answer per page would impact the experience for everyone else. It would also add a lot of extra clicks to the process, as well as time spent waiting for the new page to load. I also don't want to show the textbox from the start, just disabled, because screen-readers would still read out the label. I'm just trying to minimise any impact adding the question to the page layout would cause. Also, thank you for the extra tags edit. :)

Comment: You can display one question at a time without any load time in between if you preload as many questions as possible, load other asynchronously and use client side JavaScript controllers e.g. AngularJS to swap the displayed question. Also, you may be able to reduce the extra clicks via gestures.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mean one question per-page, but just displaying one question at a time on the same page, bringing the next one in with JScript or something like that.

Comment: Danny, I'm not sure many would recommend AngularJS for accessibility! :) The question is really about what is better for a person who has difficulty processing information, an animated div sliding slowly into visibility, or a div suddenly blinking into view?

Comment: Jon, unfortunately, your solution would potentially have the same problem as I have now. When I move to the next question, should I hide() the old one and show() the new one OR hide("slow") the old one and show("slow") the new one?

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point. Also with the screenreaders being notified that there is new content available too (it is possible to notify screenreaders of changes such as this (ARIA regions etc) but it's a development overhead). Hence why I left this as more of a comment than a full answer really as it might not be a perfect solution, but an avenue to explore.

Comment: "sliding" it onto the page, using animation" - would this not provide too much arousel? Content appearing/disappearing without distracting animations 'may' actually be less stimulating. n.b. I don't have any experience in designing specifically for these types of audience, i've just taken a quick look at http://www.autism.org.uk/working-with/leisure-and-environments/designing-websites-suitable-for-people-with-autism-spectrum-disorders.aspx

Comment: Did you consider displaying all sub-fields, but disabled/greyed out?

Comment: Dave, thank you for the link. The sliding method was a way to show the user that the content in the rest of the page was moving down, rather than confronting the user with a page that they might think had suddenly, completely changed. By animating it (slowly), I can show them what is happening. NonNumeric's suggestion below would get round this, but the designers would push against unexplained spaces on the page, so I'm looking for the answer to this blink v slide question.

Comment: Okay, for those following this question, I'm having a meeting with the National Autistic Society (in the UK) next month, about Accessibility, so, hopefully, I can get an answer from them.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try `visibility:hidden` <-> `visibility:visible` instead of `display:none` <-> `display:block` . That way there will be no scrolling of remaining questions. There will be empty space with the `No` option but with some styling it (probably) won't look too awkward. It may even serve as a hint that there is something more to the question than the radio buttons:

[image: No]

versus:

[image: Yes]

You can animate this transition as well.

Comment: Ooh, interesting! That's something I hadn't thought of.  Thanks, NonNumeric. That makes a lot of sense. Do you have any insight into how "fading-in" text versus "blinking-in" text is processed by people who have problems processing visual data?

Comment: I don't know. What I have observed (but this is only anecdotal evidence) is that even people with good visual perception sometimes fail to recognize single-frame "blinking-in" changes on screen. Animating a transition (for a second or less) catches more attention in a way that I feel might be better in your case. This is still a weak recommendation - I am not sure myself.